# Do compute shaders in OpenGl have instruction limits?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I've looked everywhere and couldn't find a definitive answer

vertex and fragment shaders do in fact have a limit on the maximum size of the shader and number of instructions, but i've never heard about those limitations on a compute shader

Since I need to port an existing CPU Path tracer with many different BRDFs I need to know in advance if this could be an issue and move to CUDA or if OpenGL's compute shaders could handle the work just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are always limits. But these limits are implementation-defined; they're not expressed in any a-priori determinable way. So the only way you'll find out what they are is to cross them.

CUDA has limits too.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I remembered CUDA had up to 2 millions of possible intructions whereas the miminum guaranteed number for a vertex shader could be as short as 512, isn't there a difference of orders of magnitude?
Do CUDA and compute shaders have absolutely no difference in instruction limits compared to vertex shaders?

Comment: [Shader Model 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509656(v=vs.85).aspx) required a minimum of 512 instructions for vertex and fragment shader, but this was introduced in 2004 (Geforce 6 Series). Already in [Shader Model 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509657(v=vs.85).aspx) (2006, Geforce 8 Series) the restriction was lifted to an unlimited number of instructions. I guess there might not be many 10 year old graphic cards around.

Comment: @RowRebel: Adding to what BDL said, what is an "instruction"? How many instructions does a particular piece of GLSL take? Even SPIR-V does not correlate 1:1 to GPU instructions. You can only specify limits in terms of implementation-dependent hardware, and while CUDA is NVIDIA-only (and therefore can specify the GPU instruction limits), OpenGL is platform-neutral. And there's no way to specify limits reasonably while still being platform-neutral. Not on modern hardware.

Comment: Thanks to all for the clarification, I didn't know the restriction was no longer in place in SM4